# ApplicationManager_ImmersiveShellWindow?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, webview2

I have an WPF based desktop application and recently some of the users started to report that they are noticing that when using my app in some cases (mostly when running full screen games) the game cursor changes from the game provided one to the classic windows cursor.

This was only happening in the lower left region of the screen above the taskbar.
After some investigation I have found that indeed that is the case. Digging deeper revealed that there is indeed an window of class `ApplicationManager_ImmersiveShellWindow` is shown over the taskbar, the window itself is invisible or perhaps has zero opacity but it does interact with the mouse.
The problem does not appear if user dont start my application and clicking on this window make it go away or close.

So the question is whether anybody knows what this problem could be related to ?
One of the changes in my application that I could attribute this to is the switch from native WPF for the UI to the new WebView2 based one although I am not sure if this could be related to it.